# Is there a formula to find the required dimensions so that all points in a collection are likely on the Pareto frontier?

Tags: probability

Given a collection of points in d dimensions, a point is on the Pareto frontier of the collection if there is no other point with a higher value in every dimension. Suppose you have a collection of n points where all coordinate values have been independently chosen from a normal distribution. Is there a formula to find the minimum number of dimensions d such that the probability that all n points are on the Pareto frontier is greater than 0.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll bite (though this is not strictly a programming question, it is also not really a question about statistics, but more of a combinatorial puzzle, and a nice one at that)

I'll re-formulate the question a bit: suppose each kid in a class of *n*  pupils draws a real number from a continuous (not necessarily normal) distribution, once every day on *d* consecutive days.

Let's call a pupil *x*  *strictly worse off* than *y* if *x* draws
a smaller number than *y* on all those days. Let's call a pair *(x,y)* an *unlucky pair*  if x is strictly worse off than y, or vice versa (the ordering of *x* and *y* doesn't matter)

The score of a pupil  *x* on *d* consecutive days determines a *d*-dimensional point *(x<sub>0</sub>, ..., x<sub>d-1</sub>)*; this point is on the Pareto frontier iff x is not strictly worse off than any other pupil.  With *n* pupils, we get *n* points in *d* dimensions, like in the original question.

The question then is to determine the chance,  that, given *n* pupils,  after *d* days, all those points are on the Pareto frontier, i.e.that there are no unlucky pairs left .

Let's pick two pupils, call them *x* and *y*. After one day the chance that they are an unlucky pair is 1, each consecutive day after that halves that chance. After *d* days the chance is *2<sup>-(d-1)</sup>*

There are *n*(n-1)/2* distinct [ways to pick such a pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859430/how-do-i-get-the-total-number-of-unique-pairs-of-a-set-in-the-database)

It is not difficult to see that, for any *x,y,u,v* (unless the pairs coincide completely), *(x,y) is unlucky* is independent from *(u,v) is unlucky* (You only need to verify this for *n=4* and *d=2*, the rest follows by induction) Note that  this uses the symmetry of *is an unlucky pair*, it wouldn't have been the case with *is strictly worse off than*)

So the chance that there are no unlucky pairs  left after d days is equal to  that of never getting a 0 when rolling a *2<sup>(d-1)</sup>*-faced die *n(n-1)/2* times.

That chance *p(n,d)* is  *(1 - 2<sup>-(d-1)</sup>)<sup>(n(n - 1)/2)</sup>*.
Plotting this with [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%281-2%5E-%28d-1%29%29%5E%28n%28n-1%29%2F2%29%2C+d%3D1..20%2Cn%3D1..20), we can see that for example, for a class of 20 pupils we'll need to go on for  around 9 days to get a 50% chance.

Note that the distribution of the draws, normal or otherwise, doesn't enter into the result..

Edit: using *(1-1/n)<sup>n</sup> ≈ e<sup>-1</sup>* and *n(n-1) ≈ n<sup>2</sup>* (for large *n*) one can write *p(n,d) ≈ e<sup>-n<sup>2</sup>/2<sup>d</sup></sup>*
So, for each doubling of *n* we need 2 more days to have the same likelihood of a draw without unlucky pairs. To get from the 20 pupils in the example above to the whole world population (8 billion) we need to double the school class about 28.5 times. That means  we'll need approximately 57 more days than the 9 above, that is 66 days.

Comment: Thanks! For n = 8 billion, WolframAlpha's graph gets funky but it looks like d is around 55, right?

Comment: See my edit above. I get approx. 66 days, not 55